# Visa for Alaskan cruise

Tags: visas, canada, uk-citizens, eta

I am from the UK. I am going on a cruise from Seattle to Alaska and was wanting to know do I need a Canadian visa/eta as the dock ships in Victoria BC? I already have an ESTA for the US.

Answer (score 4):

You only need a Canada eTA if you enter Canada by air. If you enter by land or sea, you do not need an eTA. In no case do you need a visa for a short visit.

Comment: Thank you. That is interesting to know as the cruise line are insisting that I need one.

Comment: Does it say British Citizen on your passport?

Comment: @KathleenDonnelly Canadian eTA is very inexpensive ($7, if I recall correctly, currently about £4).  If I were taking a cruise with an operator who said I needed one, I would probably just get it, even if I knew that they were wrong.

Comment: @KathleenDonnelly is it Carnival? I just looked at their site and it is full of imprecise and incorrect information about travel document requirements, notably including eTA.  You might send them to http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp or to https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/eta/facts.html, which says unambiguously "Visa-exempt foreign nationals need an eTA to fly to or transit through a Canadian airport. These travellers do not need an eTA when arriving by car, bus, train or boat (including a cruise ship)."